# best approach to use postmeta and usermeta? (Wordpress, Mysql Database)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

What i'm trying to say is that i am developing a project where i need to save some user and post data(user id and post id) when user perform a specific action his data (post id and user id) will save in database (postmeta) and then verify with wp_query that the current user have his user id against post id or not

if(Check if in database that current post id is saved against his current user id)
   // do action
else
   // don't do

So what will be the best approach right now i'm saving his current post id and current user id in wp_postmeta and verify with wp_query if his current post id matches his current user id in wp_postmeta

Is the above approach is good?

if not

what will be the best approach?

Hope you have understand my question
really appreciate your answer

Insertion Code:

```
 $new_post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$watched="watched";
global $wpdb,$user_ID;
$cur_user_id= $user_ID;
$chstr =$wpdb->get_results( "select meta_value,meta_key from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = $new_post_id AND meta_value= $cur_user_id" );

if(count($chstr) > 0){ 
    exit;
}else{
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_postmeta', 
        array( 
            'post_id'=> $new_post_id,
            'meta_key' => $new_post_id,
            'meta_value' => $cur_user_id
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
    die();
    return true;

}
```

Check if current user id and current post id exist:

```
global $wpdb,$user_ID;
$dis_post_id=get_the_ID();
$cur_use_id=$user_ID;
$checkstr =$wpdb->get_results( "select meta_value,meta_key from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key = $dis_post_id AND meta_value= $cur_use_id" );
if(count($checkstr) > 0){custom_text_to_display();}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code?

Comment: @Aliqua just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following code, it will save current user id in post metadata then you can retrieve posts from wp_query using meta query..

```
function save_post_meta_userid( $post_id ) {
    $curr_userid = get_current_user_id();
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_currentuserid', $curr_userid  );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_meta_userid' );
add_action( 'edit_post', 'save_post_meta_userid' );
```

Then using metaquery:

```
$curr_userid = get_current_user_id();
$args   =   array(
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'post_currentuserid',
        'value'     => $curr_userid,
        'compare'   => '=',
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo $query->found_posts;
```

Comment: `WP_Query()` is a much preferred option to directly querying the database. For more information you can refer to the wordpress developers website relating to wp_query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/